# Inserting user registration fields for app development

Tags: users, external-scripts

[image]

I need to insert the value as below.. but not working..

```
$fields['field_clinic_hospital_location_d']['und'][0]['field_telephone_number']['und'][0]['value'] = $telnum;
```

I am inserting the user registration fileds from external php file. field values inserting successfully in below 1st case, but not working in 2nd case. I picked this below data from the firebug name attribute which the field is `<input tag name="field..." attribute.`

```
Case1:- $fields['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value'] = $firstname;
case2:- $fields['field_contact_address']['und'][0]['thoroughfare'] = $contaddr;
```

Comment: You could try installing the devel module and using the dpm() function to print the $fields variable for a profile user that already has those values and you can see what the data structure of the field should look like. Also worth making sure the $contaddr actually has data in it.

Comment: because there is no `thoroughfare` element in `$fields['field_contact_address']['und'][0]`.

Comment: Hi Rooby.. When I clicked on Devel tab of any user profile there are 5 sub tabs (Load, Token, Render). The values are showing fine with array elements for single filed values (Ex: "field_primary_speciality" in the image). If I have field collection items then that is not array expanding completely with those values (Ex: "field_clinic_hospital_location_d" in the image). I have all contact address information in this field. I need to insert values in the filed collection values. Please see the attached image.